# Angular js gets wrong array from http get response

Tags: java, rest, jersey, httpresponse

I'm developing a web application with angularjs and Java but I'm having issues with the response array from an http get request.
I have a class Item with two constructor :

```
public Item(int IdUnit, int ProductCode, String Brand, int AvailableItems, int RequiredItems, int OrderedItems,String Note, String Option)
public Item(int chassis, int engine, int body, int equipment, int tyres_brakes)
```

This is my java method to get the request:

```
@GET
@Path("items/{unit}")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })
public Response getAllItems(@PathParam("unit") String name) {
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        Connection con = Condb.initializeDatabase();
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + name);
        Item item;
        while (rs.next()) {             
            item = new Item(rs.getInt("idUnit"), rs.getInt("productCode"), rs.getString("brand"),
                    rs.getInt("availableItems"), rs.getInt("requiredItems"), rs.getInt("orderedItems"),
                    rs.getString("note"), filterOperation.checkOptional(name, rs));
            items.add(item);
        }
        con.close();
        return Response.ok(items).build();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }
}
```

This is my list 'items' in Java debugger:
[image]

But in the browser console I got this log:
[image]

The lenght of array is correct, but the content is not.
How can I resolve this?

EDIT : This is the Item class

@XmlRootElement(name = "item")
public class Item {

```
public Item() {}

public Item(int IdUnit, int ProductCode, String Brand, int AvailableItems, int RequiredItems, int OrderedItems,String Note, String Option) {
    this.idUnit = IdUnit;
    this.productCode = ProductCode;
    this.brand = Brand;
    this.availableItems = AvailableItems;
    this.requiredItems = RequiredItems;
    this.orderedItems = OrderedItems;
    this.note = Note;
    this.option = Option;
}

public Item(int chassis, int engine, int body, int equipment, int tyres_brakes) {
    this.chassis = chassis;
    this.engine = engine;
    this.body = body;
    this.equipment = equipment;
    this.tyres_brakes = tyres_brakes;
}


private int chassis;
private int engine;
private int body;
private int equipment;
private int tyres_brakes;
final private String[] units = { "chassis", "engine", "body", "equipment", "tyres_brakes" };

@XmlElement(name = "idUnit")
private int idUnit;

@XmlElement(name = "productCode")
private int productCode;

@XmlElement(name = "brand")
private String brand;

@XmlElement(name = "availableItems")
private int availableItems;

@XmlElement(name = "requiredItems")
private int requiredItems;

@XmlElement(name = "orderedItems")
private int orderedItems;

@XmlElement(name = "note")
private String note;

@XmlElement(name = "option")
private String option;

public int getChassis() {
    return chassis;
}

public int getEngine() {
    return engine;
}

public int getBody() {
    return body;
}

public int getEquipment() {
    return equipment;
}

public int getTyres_brakes() {
    return tyres_brakes;
}

public String getUnits(int index) {
    return units[index];
}
```

}

Comment: Have you looked at the raw response over the network?

Comment: This is my raw response

Comment: [{"chassis":0,"engine":0,"body":0,"equipment":0,"tyres_brakes":0},{"chassis":0,"engine":0,"body":0,"equipment":0,"tyres_brakes":0},{"chassis":0,"engine":0,"body":0,"equipment":0,"tyres_brakes":0},{"chassis":0,"engine":0,"body":0,"equipment":0,"tyres_brakes":0},{"chassis":0,"engine":0,"body":0,"equipment":0,"tyres_brakes":0},{"chassis":0,"engine":0,"body":0,"equipment":0,"tyres_brakes":0},{"chassis":0,"engine":0,"body":0,"equipment":0,"tyres_brakes":0},{"chassis":0,"engine":0,"body":0,"equipment":0,"tyres_brakes":0}]

Comment: When you say the content is not correct - the item you've shown in the debugger *does* have zero for all of those values. So is it just a matter of it not including everything you need it to? Note that if that's the response, and it's not what you expected, then I'd remove the `angularjs` tag - the problem is with what's being returned, not how it's being consumed.

Comment: It would also really help if you'd provide a complete example. We don't know what the `Item` class looks like. For example, if it has public properties for chassis, engine, body, equipment, and tyres_brakes, but not for anything else, that may very well give you a clue...

Comment: You're right, the angularjs response doesn't include all the elements I need (that are those in Java Response list). I edited the question with the Item class

Comment: Right - notice how everything that's being returned has a public "getter" method? Try doing the same for other things that you *want* to be returned, but which *aren't* currently being returned...

Comment: You saved my day! Thank you so much. I added the getter methods and now it works!